# How should i use Google Api Key when connecting Google+ Sign In?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, development-environment

I can't understand. But when I sing in on Google Developers Console there under Credentials pressed New Credentials -> OAuth client ID, and then chose the WebApplication. Everything is as it was in the developers.google.com ...

It gave me the result:

Here is your client ID 862620552316

Here is your client secret HnnUSPTbqoNdt5ry8M6Fd1Gi

How i should use it? I'm nowhere use it in my app. Could it be a reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: what are u trying to do ?

Answer (score -1):

You are not providing information about the library that you are using to connect to the OAuth service.

Assuming you are using Google's OAuth Client library, here is a good explanation, with examples, about how to use client id and secret:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2

EDIT: providing your code and screenshots from Google's Developers Console (with erased private data) maybe could help to detect your problem.